# increasing the limit for cubedata.h in postgres on windows

Tags: python, windows, postgresql

I'm working on a facial recognition project and I need to store the encodings on postgres database but there is a limit to the CUBE datatype of 100. I read in the documentation that we could change this from the cubedata.h file but I don't know how since I'm a beginner in postgres. Could someone explain to me the steps involved to partake this procedure on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I finally decided to dual boot my system with linux and followed the steps given on how to do this.I'll paste the link here for future reference and in case someone else might be interested.

https://www.rathishkumar.in//2021/03/face-recognition-euclidean-distance-sql.html

here you'll find the shorter version but for a detailed description you could download the source code for postgres and read the INSTALL file.